# Score tally is off by a factor of 10

Tags: support, tag-wiki, privileges

For the two tags that I've checked, my score tally is one-tenth of what it actually is. For example, for the Perl tag I get the following:

["To edit this wiki, you must have a total score of 100 on non-community-wiki answers in this tag (you currently have 21), and at least 2000 reputation."](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info)

I think my tally is more like 210.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're confusing **vote** score and **reputation** score.

As each vote is worth 10 reputation points, with 21 votes you'll have 210 reputation points.

Comment: @molecules: Note this is because not all votes turn into reputation with the daily reputation limit, so tracking actual votes is what affects tag-wiki-edit ability.

Comment: Thanks. To be more clear, I would refactor the message to be "To edit this wiki, you must have a total of 100 up-votes (less any down votes) on non-community-wiki answers in this tag (you currently have 21), and at least 2000 reputation."